# Parsing of optional static text in a Lua string?

Tags: string, lua

I have a scenario in which I need to be able to match an optional static portion of text in a string, but that static portion could be 1 of 2 possibilities.

Here are some examples of possibilities that I need to be able to parse:

```
"foo + offset bar"

"*foo + bar"

"foo + bar"

"*foo + *bar"

"offset foo + offset bar"
```

where either `"offset"` or `"*"` should be optional in front of each identifier. (in this case "foo" and "bar")

Is there any actual way to do this using Lua's string matching? I was thinking of something like:

`"[offset]?%s*%*?%s*[_%a][_%w]*"` but `"[offset]?"` is only an optional character class that can either be `o, f, s, e, or t;` and even if it wasn't users would be able to send input like:

```
"offset * foo + offset * bar"
```

without getting a proper warning.

From a pseudo-code standpoint, what I am trying to do would probably look something like

```
("offset" or "*" or "") and "%s*[_%a][_%w]*"
```

To sum it up, is there any way to match an optional static portion or portions of text in a string using Lua's string matching system?

Thanks

Comment: I am not aware of a possibiity to match optional specific words like you can do with single characters. I guess you'll have to do several matches and combine them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily replace keyword "offset" with some unused symbol (for example, "@") and then parse the result:

```
local input_strings = {
   "foo + offset bar"       ,
   "*foo + bar"             ,
   "foo + bar"              ,
   "*foo + *bar"            ,
   "offset foo + offset bar",
   "offset1 + offset2"
}
for _, s in ipairs(input_strings) do
   print("Expression: "..s)
   s = s:gsub("%f[%w_]offset%f[^%w_]", "@")         -- convert keyword to "@"
   for prefix, identifier in s:gmatch"([%@%*]?)%s*([_%a][_%w]*)" do
      prefix = prefix == "@" and "offset" or prefix -- convert "@" to keyword
      print("Prefix: "..prefix)
      print("Identifier: "..identifier)
   end
   print()
end
```

Output:

```
Expression: foo + offset bar
Prefix: 
Identifier: foo
Prefix: offset
Identifier: bar

Expression: *foo + bar
Prefix: *
Identifier: foo
Prefix: 
Identifier: bar

Expression: foo + bar
Prefix: 
Identifier: foo
Prefix: 
Identifier: bar

Expression: *foo + *bar
Prefix: *
Identifier: foo
Prefix: *
Identifier: bar

Expression: offset foo + offset bar
Prefix: offset
Identifier: foo
Prefix: offset
Identifier: bar

Expression: offset1 + offset2
Prefix: 
Identifier: offset1
Prefix: 
Identifier: offset2
```